# Concern in Managing Platform-Specific Features

Tags: architecture, cross-platform, software-design, circular-dependency, platform-specific

I'm wondering how to address a concern I have. I have a "foo" and multiple conditional platform-specific "foos" (e.g., winFoo, LinuxFoo, or AndroidFoo), where all the platform-specific ones depend on the base "foo." I'm struggling with deciding whether to create a platform-agnostic "foo" and add platform-specific functionality conditionally within it. This approach would offer flexibility, but it means that if I include the platform-specific "foo," it won't have the base "foo" functionality, and attempting to add it could result in an unsightly circular dependency.

Alternatively, I'm considering having the platform-specific "foos" use the base agnostic "foo" and conditionally include them using "if-else" statements in all the places where they are needed. While this approach may work, it's not as flexible as I'd like, and I'm trying to find a balanced solution that offers flexibility while maintaining a smooth and elegant structure. What recommendations do you have?

Comment: Could you please give more introduction? What is "foo" in your case? It's just a string or something more?

Comment: say for example "utils" as platform agnostic and "winUtils" as plataform specific

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in following way:

1. Create common interface for all platform specific modules. Define there classes and methods which all platform specific modules should implement.
2. In platform specific modules implement logic following defined interface module.
3. To avoid circular dependency, implement `builder` module where core "foo" module is used together with platform specific module, but only using interface(you can use template method as design pattern). To avoid if-elses, you can select proper implementation of interface based on some argument.

Forgive me, if I understood something wrong, we can adjust it in comments together.

Comment: Amazing, but that means there will be a constraint on the direct usage of platform-specific module 'winFoo,' (maybe in the context of testing) which means you'll be compelled to use the core 'foo' module, right?"

Comment: I would suggest using platform specific module via builder module. For example, provide params, that `build` module will generate platform specific implementation with "foo" logic. Core "foo" module and platform specific module should be covered by separated tests

Comment: `builder module` , what it means

Comment: Another module, where you have dependency to core "foo" module, "interface" module and all platform specific module

Comment: I'm still struggling to grasp the concept of the `builder module` in the context of CMake. Could you please provide a straightforward example? Let's consider the `utils` and `winUtils` modules, where `winUtils` relies on platform-agnostic features from `utils`, and `utils` defines interfaces for `winUtils` to implement, taking platform-specific requirements into account.